# How to lock screen OSX without setting “immediately” in Security & Privacy settings

Tags: macos

I would like to lock my OSX screen at any time, irrespective of whether "Immediately" is configured in the general tab in Security & Privacy settings.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keychain Access App is located in the Utilities subfolder of the Applications folder.

In the Keychain Access App, open **Preferences** and under the **General** tab you can tick the box **Show Keychain status in menu bar**. It'll put a padlock symbol that's resident in your menu bar that when clicked will provide you with a menu, the first menu item is **Lock Screen**. After setting the preference you can exit the Keychain Access App.

You can select the menu item to lock your screen.

Comment: You are the BOSS!

Answer (score 0):

To lock your Mac’s screen, simultaneously press the following keys: `Control + Shift + Eject`. If you have a newer Mac that doesn’t have an optical drive (and thus has no eject key on the keyboard, such as the Retina MacBook Pro), the command is `Control + Shift + Power`.

In both cases, you’ll see your Mac’s display shut off immediately, while the system continues to run in the background.

Comment: I want to lock even when "Immediately" is not set, and that requieres "Immediately"  to be set